# Find an example such that $X$ with the lexicographic order is not well-ordered.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

> Let $\{A_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a collection of well-ordered sets. $X$ is defined by $X=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$. Find an example such that $X$ with the lexicographic order is not well-ordered.

I know that if $X$ were defined by finite Cartesian product, it would necessarily be a well-ordered set with the lexicographic order.  But I don't know how to find an example so it won't be well ordered.
Thanks

Comment: How exactly is lexicographic order defined (there is apparently more than one version of it).

Comment: Hint: Consider $A_n=\mathbb{N}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, can you construct a descending sequence?

Comment: @JustinBenfield the lexicographic order is defined by $(a_1,b_1)\le (a_2,b_2)$ iff $a_1\lt a_2 $ or $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1\le b_2$.

Comment: @JustinBenfield Do you mean by descending sequence a sequence that is eventually constant at some point?

Comment: No, it must not be constant, you want to find a subset of the product of the $A_n$'s that doesn't have a least element (to show that it isn't well-ordered). See my answer for an explicit construction.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma This is only true for finite products! (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the collection $\{ A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $A_n=\mathbb{N}$ each with the usual well-order given by $\leq$.

We will construct a decreasing sequence of elements as follows, to begin, choose an element  $(a_1,a_2,...)\in\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n$ so that none of the $a_i=1$. Then construct a new element, $(a_1-1,a_2,...)$ which is also in the product, but occurs earlier in the lexicographic order. Next we construct $(a_1-1,a_2-1,...)$ and so forth.

Thus we have a sequence $(\alpha_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, where

$\alpha_k=(a_1-1,...,a_{k-1}-1,a_k,...)$.

This sequence satisfies $\alpha_k\leq\alpha_{k-1}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and hence the set $\{\alpha_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ does not have a least element, and thus the lexicographic order is not a well-order.

Comment: It would be more correct to choose $a_n < b_n$ in $A_n$ and fix them and use the sequence of all $b_n$, replacing them succesively by the $a_n$; $a_n -1$ is undefined in general.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It's perfectly well-defined in the present case, as I specified that each $A_n=\mathbb{N}$ (and that $a_i\neq 1$, thus $a_i-1$ is well-defined). For the general version of the problem, yes that construction is needed, but the original question only asked for an example, so I gave an easy one.

Comment: ok, I thought you gave a more general example

Answer (score 0):

Let  $A=\{0,1\}$ with $0<1.$ For $k\in N$ let $x_k=(x_{k,n})_{n\in N}\in A^N, $ where $x_{k,n}=1$ if $n\geq k,$ and $x_{k,n}=0$ if $n<k. $ Then $x_k>x_{k+1}.$

Remark : On the set $S$ of all $y\in [0,1)$ such that $y$ has a base-$3$ representation without using the digit $2,$ the natural (arithmetic) order on $S$ co-incides with the lexicographic order on the sequences of digits (without using the digit $2$) of members of $S.$ And this is just the lex order on $\{0,1\}^N.$ Clearly $S\cap (0,1)$ is not empty and has no least member.